# Inverse of a block matrix with singular diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I have a special case where $$X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C & 0
\end{array}\right)$$ and:

1. $X$ is non-singular
2. $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is singular
3. $B \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ is full column rank
4. $C\in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ is full row rank
5. $D \ = 0_{m\times m}$

How do you calculate $X^{-1}$ in this case?

For example, $$X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It may not change the analysis, but what are the dimensions of the submatrices?

Comment: In general this matrix is not invertible - take $A$ and $D$ sto be $m\times m$ and $n\times n$ respectively. If $m>n$ and $A=0$ then the rank of $X$ is $2n$, which is less than $m+n$.

Comment: An example of X is $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are looking for a blockwise closed-form formula in terms of $A,B$ and $C$, I am very skeptical about its usefulness. Yet that doesn't mean there isn't one: since $X$ is invertible,
$$
X^{-1} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T
={\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}A^TA+C^TC & A^TB\\ B^TA & B^TB\end{bmatrix}}_M}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}A^T & C^T\\ B^T & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As $X$ is invertible, $M=X^TX$ is positive definite. Hence the diagonal sub-block $B^TB$ is invertible (and in fact, positive definite). In turn, its [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) in $M$ is also invertible. By applying the matrix inversion formula in terms of Schur complement, we get
$$
X^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
S^{-1} &
-S^{-1} A^TB (B^TB)^{-1} \\
-(B^TB)^{-1} B^TA S^{-1} &
(B^TB)^{-1} + (B^TB)^{-1} B^TA S^{-1} A^TB (B^TB)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A^T & C^T\\ B^T & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $S=A^TA+C^TC-A^TB(B^TB)^{-1}B^TA$ is the Schur complement of $B^TB$ in $M$.

---

**Edit.** The above idea can be generalised to any invertible complex matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\ C&D\end{bmatrix}$ with square diagonal sub-blocks $A$ and $D$ of possibly different sizes. We have
\begin{aligned}
X^{-1} = (X^\ast X)^{-1}X^\ast
&={\begin{bmatrix}A^\ast A+C^\ast C & A^\ast B+C^\ast D\\ B^\ast A+D^\ast C & B^\ast B+D^\ast D\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}A^\ast & C^\ast\\ B^\ast & D^\ast\end{bmatrix}\\
&=:{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}P&Q\\ Q^\ast&R\end{bmatrix}}_M}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}A^\ast & C^\ast\\ B^\ast & D^\ast\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
where $P= A^\ast A+C^\ast C,\ Q=A^\ast B+C^\ast D$ and $R=B^\ast B+D^\ast D$.

Since $X$ is invertible, $M=X^\ast X$ is positive definite. Thus the principal submatrices $R$ and its Schur complement $S=P-QR^{-1}Q^\ast$ in $M$ are also positive definite and we may apply the usual block matrix inverse formula to $M$ to obtain
$$
X^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
S^{-1} & -S^{-1} QR^{-1} \\
-R^{-1}Q^\ast S^{-1} & R^{-1} + R^{-1}Q^\ast S^{-1}QR^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A^\ast & C^\ast\\ B^\ast & D^\ast\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question!

Comment: user1551, can I get your contact information? I want to acknowledge you in my dissertation and in any publications if I get them.

Comment: @Shyam Thanks, but I would like to remain anonymous. See [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4260/1551) and footnote 7 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0325v2.pdf) for an example of citing $\mathtt{mathoverflow.net}$. In our case, you may write something like "this fact was explained to us by an anonymous user ($\mathtt{user1551}$) of $\mathtt{math.stackexchange.com}$ in answer no. 412136 to question no. 411492."