# Eigenvalues of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

For $X=\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & B\\ C & 0\end{array}\right)$, how are eigenvalues of $X$ related to the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much can be said. However, if $A$ is square and $X$ is Hermitian (hence $A$ is Hermitian and $C=B^\ast$) and $\lambda_1(M)\le\lambda_2(M)\le\lambda_3(M)\cdots$ denote the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix $M$ arranged in increasing order, we have the following *interlacing inequality*:
$$
\lambda_k(X)\le\lambda_k(A)\le\lambda_{k+n-r}(X)
$$
for $1\le k\le r$, when $A$ is $r\times r$ and $X$ is $n\times n$.

Also, if the four blocks have equal sizes, the characteristic polynomial of $X$ can be simplified as follows:
$$
\det\pmatrix{xI-A&-B\\ -C&xI} = \det(x^2I - xA - BC).
$$
Such simplification is valid because the two blocks at the bottom of the LHS commute. You can see that $\det(x^2I - xA - BC)$ has little resemblance to $\det(\lambda I-A)$ and we don't expect any relationship between the eigenvalues of $X$ and $A$ in general.

Comment: What if all the eigenvalues of X are strictly negative but X is not Hermitian, will that tell any thing about A? (If X was Hermitian, eigenvalues of A would have been strictly negative according to the inequality)

Comment: @Shyam Almost nothing, except that eigenvalues of $A$ (when $A$ is a square matrix) must sum up to a negative number, because $A$ and $X$ have the same trace. $A$ can have positive or even nonreal eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This question is related to a problem of block inverse that I am trying to solve, can you help me with that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411492/inverse-of-a-block-matrix

Comment: What is $n$? Is that the number of _unique_ eigenvalues? In other words, do you arrange the eigenvalues with multiplicity?

Comment: But then in the interlacing inequality, $n$ is equal to either the size of $A$ or the size of $X$? Come to think of it, what is the size of $X$? By the way, thanks for replying so quickly on a question from 2 years ago.

Comment: @EricS. Please see my new edit.

Comment: Thanks for editing! And once again, thank you for your quick responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Say that for some v, $ Av = \lambda v $ and $ C v = 0 $. Then letting $ w = \left(\begin{array}{c}
v \\
0 
\end{array}\right) $, what is $ X w $? Similarly if $ w = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y 
\end{array}\right) $ is an eigenvalue of $ X $ and $ B y = 0 $, then what is $ A x$?

Comment: Oops, I was fixing that while you commented. Thanks anyway.