# Inverse of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix with a zero diagonal block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I want to compute the inverse of the $2\times2$ block matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & P\\ P^T & 0\end{array}\right),$$

where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $P$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.

I only come across formulas for
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C & D\\
\end{array}\right)^{-1}
$$
that involve $D^{-1}$. However, in my case $D=0$, such that $D$ has no inverse and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: One of the Related questions may be helpful, [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411492/inverse-of-a-block-matrix?rq=1) in particular.

Comment: This might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) does not involve $D^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks, I just found it myself as well. Wanted to say just that when I saw your answer. I started searching in papers - guess I should trust Wikipedia more often :p