# Prove that a block matrix whose blocks are diagonal or tridiagonal matrices and are monotone is also monotone

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ A_3 & A_4 \end{pmatrix}$$

is a block matrix with all blocks of order $n$ by $n$. Blocks $A_2$ and $A_3$ are diagonal matrices with non-negative entries. Blocks $A_1$ and $A_4$ are tridiagonal matrices and also [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_matrix). Prove that $A$ is a monotone matrix. I have approached the question as :
Writing $$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_4 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A_2 \\ A_3 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = A1 + A2 $$
We have $A1$ is monotone matrix because it is a block diagonal matrix whose diagonals are monotone matrices. Now how do I prove that adding $A2$ to $A1$  will also give a monotone matrix ($A_2$ and $A_3$ are diagonal matrices.)
(A is monotone if for every column vector v, $Av≥0⟹v=0$. Equivalently, it means that $A^{−1}$ exists and has only non-negative entries.)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: $A$ is monotone if for every column vector $v$, $Av \ge 0 \implies v=0$. Equivalently, it means that $A^{-1}$ exisrs and has only non-negative entries.

Comment: @founderv Are you not convinced with my answer ? If you have questions, type in the comments below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem to be true in general:

See:
Look at [Inverse of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946713/inverse-of-a-2-times-2-block-matrix)

For $A^{-1}$ has non-negative entries  $ \implies (A_4-A_3A_1^{-1}A_2)^{-1}$ has non-negative and $-(A_4-A_3A_1^{-1}A_2)^{-1} A_3 A_1^{-1}$ has non-negative entries.

Since $A_3$,$A_1^{-1}$ and $(A_4-A_3A_1^{-1}A_2)^{-1}$ has non-negative entries, implies $-(A_4-A_3A_1^{-1}A_2)^{-1} A_3 A_1^{-1}$ is not a matrix with positive entries.

Implies $A_3 = 0$.

By similar argument, we can conclude that $A_2 = 0$ and the resulting matrix is block diagonal monotone matrix and hence monotone.

Hence $A$ is monotone $\iff$ $A_2 = 0, A_3 = 0$.

Comment: The proof is not clear and looks false. You should assume that $Av \ge 0$, not that $v \ge 0$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan have edited the answer. Please take a look at it now.

Comment: @Balajisb I understand your answer but, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are not zero. So this does not help me.

Comment: @founderv my answer is A is monotone $\iff$ $A_2 = 0$ and $A_3 = 0$. Hence it says if $A_2 \neq 0$ or $A_3 \neq 0$ then $A$ is not monotone.

Comment: @Balajisb Okay, thanks. Got it!

Comment: @founderv if you are convinced, accept the answer by clicking on the side.