# Need help on simplifying an analytical solution to quadratic programming problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to find the analytical solution to the following problem

\begin{align}
\min_c & \; c^T Wc \\
\text{s.t. } & \; Xc = x_0
\end{align}
where $c,x_0 \in\mathbb R^n$, $W$ is an invertible $n\times n$ diagonal matrix, $X$ is a $m\times n$ matrix.

---

It's easy to show with Lagrange multiplier that the solution $c^*$ satisfies
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
W & -X^T\\
X & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c^*\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
x_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

With the method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/412136), we can find that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
W & -X^T\\
X & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
 = \begin{pmatrix}
\left[W^TW+X^TX + W^T(-X^T)(XX^T)^{-1}(-X)W \right]^{-1}  &  **\\
** & **
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
W & X^T\\
-X & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\= \begin{pmatrix}
** & \left[W^TW+X^TX + W^T(-X^T)(XX^T)^{-1}(-X)W \right]^{-1}X^T\\
** & **
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(** are irrelevant elements in calculation.)

Thus
$$
c^* = \left[W^TW+X^TX + W^T(-X^T)(XX^T)^{-1}(-X)W \right]^{-1}X^Tx_0
$$

---

It seems complicated. I read in a note that
$$
c^* = WX^T (XWX^T)^{-1} {x}_0
$$

Are they equivalent and how can I simplify the expression? Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear system boils down to $Wc^* = X^T\lambda$ and $Xc = x_0$. The first equation gives you $c^*=W^{-1}X^T\lambda$, and plugging that into the second equation you get $XW^{-1}X^T\lambda=x_0$. That means $\lambda=(XW^{-1}X^T)^{-1}x_0$, so $c^*=W^{-1}X^T(XW^{-1}X^T)^{-1}x_0$.